# Regular expression for binary strings containing at least one $1$ and at most two $0$'s

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

This question comes from [CodeStepByStep RegEx Exercise 5](https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/general/regex/regex5), and I have been banging my head against a wall for the past hour and a half trying to figure it out. I am by no means capable at writing regular expressions, and so the idea of checking for number of occurrences confuses me. The first three problems in the exercise were easy enough, though I can't see how the last is possible.

> Write a regular expression that will match the following pattern: Binary strings containing at least one 1 and at most two 0's

Comment: What about 11*01*01*+1*011*01*+1*01*011*+11*01*+1*011*+11*. The first 3 cases cover the 2 "0" cases, the next 2 ones the 1 "0" case and the last one the 0 "0" case. There is probably a simpler way to write it though.

Comment: @Anthony that apparently fails the "1" case.

Comment: The 1 case should be covered by the 11* case since 1* can be the empty word but I may be wrong

Comment: It might be a syntax issue, by + I meant the "or" operator, I think it is worth trying 11*01*01*|1*011*01*|1*01*011*|11*01*|1*011*|11*

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: The more compact way to do it using (extended) POSIX syntax is `1+0?1*0?1*|1*0?1+0?1*|1*0?1*0?1+`.